# Get query fields from ReadOnlyModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Tell me, please, how you can access the fields that were sent in the GET request to the ViewSet of the following form:

```
class MyViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data # < attempt to access this attribute will return an empty dictionary

        return super().list(request, args, kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by docs you should use `.query_params`

> request.query_params is a more correctly named synonym for request.GET.

more details [query_params](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params)